# video.js onComplete function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, video.js

Pretty simple question, but can't seem to find anything searching google or the docs. I'm using video.js for our player but trying to call an alert at the end of the video. Is there an onComplete function like jwplayer?

Answer (score 0):

They have an event called "ended"

So, to handle the completion of the video, you should be able to use code like this:

```
var myFunc = function(){
   var myPlayer = this;
   // Do something when the event is fired
 };
 myPlayer.on("ended", myFunc);
```

Comment: It's actually `on`. `myPlayer.on("ended", myFunc);`